# How to read a particular tag data from longtext type in mysql?

Tags: mysql, longtext

I am new to database so please advise me how to read data from a longtext(clob data type) in my sql.

The longtext field name is Rest_Server and the value tag to be read is  from that.

Comment: how do you mean "read data" are you wanting to read the whole data or manipulate a portion of it in some way?

Comment: I want to read just a part of the clob data which contains the tag

Comment: you're not giving INFORMATION. "just read it" is too ambigious, are you talking about reading it after the database provider has done its work, are you talking about reading it during query, manipulation though string functions etc, are you talking about reading it via the command line .... expand your question and provide some real information, use case and what you're trying to do, and what you've already tried and someone will help.  Also in MySQL world it is refereed to as a BLOB

Comment: Reading the data means retrieving through firing a query

Comment: then it will be no different than reading any other data type - just select the column Rest_Server as you would with any other.

Comment: it is like I want to read a specific tag say <money> tag value from the longtext data...

Comment: OK that's a bit different than the question implys. What kind of data is held within? Is it XML or non structured tags. I would suggest you edit your question with more detail and even a bit of sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select substr(clob_column,INSTR(clob_column,''),lengthOfTag) from table